# How to fix following issue to show Date Wise inventory records in SSRS from Microsoft Dynamics AX

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, axapta

I am new Microsoft Dynamics AX Business Analyst. I am writing an SQL Query to show Date Wise Inventory Records Like Opening Stock, Net Dispatch, Sold Stock, Transferred Out Stock, Stock Adjustment and Closing Stock.
I wrote a query which displaying following records between @FromDate=2013-11-01 and @ToDate=2014-01-01.
There are 518 Records fetching. I have no concern to show upto first 398 records in Report because these are Before Date records to calculate opening Stock.
Problems are :
1. I don't want to show these (Before @FromDate)records on report what condition can be used to hide them.
2. Closing stock of Previous Date must be equivalent to Opening Stock of Next Day.But u can see in Figure 3 it is not so that.

**NOTE:** I sum up all the Quantities(Like Sum(OpeningStock)) one by one. It shows exact number of units.
[image]
Figure-1
[image]
Figure-2
[image]
Figure-3

**Here Is the SQL Query.**

```
SELECT TempTable.Dated, TempTable.BusinessGroup,
       ISNULL(SUM(Opening),0) OpeningStock, ISNULL(SUM(Dispatched),0) NetDispatched,
       (ISNULL(SUM(Opening),0) + ISNULL(SUM(Dispatched),0)) TotalStock,
       ISNULL(SUM(Sold),0) SoldStock, ISNULL(SUM(TransferredOut),0) TransferOutStock,
       ISNULL(SUM(StockAdjustment),0) StockAdjustment,
       (ISNULL(SUM(Opening),0)+ISNULL(SUM(Dispatched),0)-ISNULL(SUM(Sold),0)-ISNULL(SUM(TransferredOut),0)+ISNULL(SUM(StockAdjustment),0)) ClosingStock   
FROM
(
    /*------------------Opening---------------------------*/
    SELECT CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName,SUM(CSM.Qty) Opening,
      0 Dispatched, 0 Sold, 0 TransferredOut, 0 StockAdjustment,CSM.OtherLocation
    FROM dbo.Mtq_CompleteStockMovement AS CSM 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTTABLE AS IT ON CSM.ITEMID = IT.ITEMID AND CSM.DataAreaID = IT.DATAAREAID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RBOINVENTTABLE AS RIT ON RIT.ITEMID=IT.ITEMID AND RIT.DATAAREAID=IT.DATAAREAID
    WHERE CSM.DataAreaID='tcl' AND CSM.LabelId <>3 AND CSM.InventLocationID='SW143' AND CSM.Dated < '2013-11-01' 
    GROUP BY CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName,CSM.OtherLocation

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName,SUM(CSM.Qty) Opening,
      0 Dispatched, 0 Sold, 0 TransferredOut, 0 StockAdjustment,CSM.OtherLocation
    FROM dbo.Mtq_CompleteStockMovement AS CSM 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTTABLE AS IT ON CSM.ITEMID = IT.ITEMID AND CSM.DataAreaID = IT.DATAAREAID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RBOINVENTTABLE AS RIT ON RIT.ITEMID=IT.ITEMID AND RIT.DATAAREAID=IT.DATAAREAID
    WHERE CSM.DataAreaID='tcl' AND CSM.LabelId =4 AND CSM.OtherLocation='SW143' AND CSM.Dated < '2013-11-01' 
    GROUP BY CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName,CSM.OtherLocation

    UNION ALL

    /*---------------------Dispatch----------------------*/
    /****Transfer in****/
    SELECT CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName, 0 Opening,
      SUM(CSM.Qty) Dispatched, 0 Sold, 0 TransferredOut, 0 StockAdjustment, CSM.OtherLocation
    FROM dbo.Mtq_CompleteStockMovement AS CSM 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTTABLE AS IT ON CSM.ITEMID = IT.ITEMID AND CSM.DataAreaID = IT.DATAAREAID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RBOINVENTTABLE AS RIT ON RIT.ITEMID=IT.ITEMID AND RIT.DATAAREAID=IT.DATAAREAID
    WHERE CSM.DataAreaID='tcl' AND CSM.LabelId =4 AND CSM.InventLocationID='SW143' AND CSM.Dated BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2014-01-01'

    GROUP BY CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName,CSM.OtherLocation

    UNION ALL
    /***Purchase Order***/
    SELECT CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName, 0 Opening,
      SUM(CSM.Qty) Dispatched, 0 Sold, 0 TransferredOut, 0 StockAdjustment, CSM.OtherLocation
    FROM dbo.Mtq_CompleteStockMovement AS CSM 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTTABLE AS IT ON CSM.ITEMID = IT.ITEMID AND CSM.DataAreaID = IT.DATAAREAID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RBOINVENTTABLE AS RIT ON RIT.ITEMID=IT.ITEMID AND RIT.DATAAREAID=IT.DATAAREAID
    WHERE CSM.DataAreaID='tcl' AND CSM.LabelId =1 AND CSM.InventLocationID='SW143' AND CSM.Dated BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2014-01-01'

    GROUP BY CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName,CSM.OtherLocation

    UNION ALL

    /***------------------Sales---------------------***/
    SELECT CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName, 0 Opening,
      0 Dispatched, SUM(CSM.Qty * -1)Sold, 0 TransferredOut, 0 StockAdjustment, CSM.OtherLocation
    FROM dbo.Mtq_CompleteStockMovement AS CSM 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTTABLE AS IT ON CSM.ITEMID = IT.ITEMID AND CSM.DataAreaID = IT.DATAAREAID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RBOINVENTTABLE AS RIT ON RIT.ITEMID=IT.ITEMID AND RIT.DATAAREAID=IT.DATAAREAID
    WHERE CSM.DataAreaID='tcl' AND CSM.LabelId =6 AND CSM.InventLocationID='SW143' AND CSM.Dated BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2014-01-01'

    GROUP BY CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName,CSM.OtherLocation

    UNION ALL
    /***---------------Transfer out------------------***/
    SELECT CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName, 0 Opening,
     0 Dispatched, 0 Sold, SUM(CSM.Qty) TransferredOut, 0 StockAdjustment, CSM.OtherLocation
    FROM dbo.Mtq_CompleteStockMovement AS CSM 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTTABLE AS IT ON CSM.ITEMID = IT.ITEMID AND CSM.DataAreaID = IT.DATAAREAID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RBOINVENTTABLE AS RIT ON RIT.ITEMID=IT.ITEMID AND RIT.DATAAREAID=IT.DATAAREAID
    WHERE CSM.DataAreaID='tcl' AND CSM.LabelId =3 AND CSM.InventLocationID='SW143' AND CSM.Dated BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2014-01-01'

    GROUP BY CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName,CSM.OtherLocation

    UNION ALL
    /***------------Stock Adjustment--------------***/
    SELECT CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName, 0 Opening,
      0 Dispatched, 0 Sold, 0 TransferredOut, SUM(CSM.Qty) StockAdjustment, CSM.OtherLocation
    FROM dbo.Mtq_CompleteStockMovement AS CSM 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTTABLE AS IT ON CSM.ITEMID = IT.ITEMID AND CSM.DataAreaID = IT.DATAAREAID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RBOINVENTTABLE AS RIT ON RIT.ITEMID=IT.ITEMID AND RIT.DATAAREAID=IT.DATAAREAID
    WHERE CSM.DataAreaID='tcl' AND CSM.LabelId =5 AND CSM.InventLocationID='SW143' AND CSM.Dated BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2014-01-01'

    GROUP BY CSM.Dated,RIT.BUSINESSGROUP,RIT.DIVISIONGROUP,RIT.ITEMDEPARTMENT,CSM.InventLocationID,CSM.ITEMID,IT.ITEMNAME,RIT.SEASONCODE,CSM.LabelId,CSM.LabelName,CSM.OtherLocation
) AS TempTable

GROUP BY TempTable.Dated, TempTable.BusinessGroup
ORDER BY TempTable.Dated, TempTable.BusinessGroup
```

Thanks for Help in Advance.